# EvernoteSession authenticateWithViewController:completionHandler: does not trigger completionHandler

Tags: ios, ios6, objective-c-blocks, evernote

When I authenticate within the iPhone Simulater in debug mode the first `if` statement in the code below is run. However, when I debug on an iPhone that has the Evernote client installed the `if` statement does not appear evaluated. Instead the Evernote iOS app comes up for just a moment, then straight back to this ViewController without hitting any set breakpoints below the if, or the segue being fired.

Any ideas?

```
[session authenticateWithViewController:self completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error || !session.isAuthenticated){
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error authenticating with Evernote Cloud API: %@", error);
        }
        if (!session.isAuthenticated) {
            NSLog(@"Session not authenticated");
        }
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Could not authenticate"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        // We're authenticated!
        EvernoteUserStore *userStore = [EvernoteUserStore userStore];
        [userStore getUserWithSuccess:^(EDAMUser *user) {
            // success
            NSLog(@"Authenticated as %@", [user username]);

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"introductionStepOne" sender:self];
        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            // failure
            NSLog(@"Error getting user: %@", error);
        } ];
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you modify your AppDelegate properly. More information here : https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-ios#modify-your-appdelegate

You need to add :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:      (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
BOOL canHandle = NO;
    if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"en-%@", [[EvernoteSession sharedSession] consumerKey]]     isEqualToString:[url scheme]] == YES) {
    canHandle = [[EvernoteSession sharedSession] canHandleOpenURL:url];
    }
    return canHandle;
}
```

And

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was     inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user     interface.
    [[EvernoteSession sharedSession] handleDidBecomeActive];
}
```

Comment: Could you share the code for Swift?
I cannot find the method which is matched with `handleDidBecomeActive`. Thank you.